# Each probability measure on a countable space comes from a weight function

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

In my lecture notes on probability theory it says that given a countable set $\Omega$ with a $\sigma$-algebra $\cal{F}$ each probability measure on $(\Omega,\cal{F})$ is induced by a function $p:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\sum_{\omega \in \Omega}p(\omega)=1$.
In case that $\cal{F}$ is the power set of $\Omega$ this is clear to me, but in the general setting it is not.

Comment: For each point $x\in\Omega$ take the smallest element $A_x$ of the $\sigma$-algebra that contains it. Define $p(x)$ to be the measure of $A_x$ divided by the cardinality of $A_x$ if $A_x$ is finite. If $A_x$ is infinite, enumerate $A_x=\{x_1,x_2,...\}$ and define $p(x_i)$ to be the measure of $A_x$ divided by $2^i$.

Comment: Thanks. This indeed is well-defined, (the second case) as for $x$ arbitrary we have that for $y\in A_x$ we have $A_y=A_x$ because else we could construct $B \subsetneq A_x$ measurable with $x\in B$. With this we also show that the sum over $p(x)$ is equal to $1$ or am I missing anything essential?

Comment: The existence of the *smallest* measurable set containing a point requires a proof.

Comment: The problem of taking the intersection of all measurable sets containing a certain point, is that this might be an uncountable intersection?!

Comment: But don't worry, since the space is countable only countably many of them actually cut out some point from the intersection. Therefore you can replace the uncountable intersection with a countable one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On $\Omega$ define the relation:$$x\sim y\iff \forall A\in\mathcal F[\{x,y\}\subseteq A\vee\{x,y\}\subseteq A^{\complement}]$$

This can be shown to be an equivalence relation. Reflexivity and symmetry is evident and if $x\sim y\wedge y\sim z$ then the existence of a set $A\in\mathcal F$ with $x\in A\wedge z\notin A$ leads to a contradiction of $x\sim y$ if $y\notin A$ and to a contradiction of $y\sim z$ if $y\in A$.

Let $[x]$ denote the equivalence class.  For every $y\notin[x]$ there is a set $A_y\in\mathcal F$ that does not contain $x$ so that $[x]^{\complement}=\bigcup_{y\notin[x]}A_y$. So if $\Omega$ is countable then $[x]\in\mathcal F$ because $\bigcup_{y\notin[x]}A_y$ is then a countable union of elements in $\mathcal F$.

So we end up with a partition of elements of $\mathcal F$ that are not empty and are such that a non-empty subset of such an element is not an element of $\mathcal F$. Then $\mathcal F$ will be exactly the collection of the unions of such sets.

As described in the comments you can now define $p:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ as a function prescribed by: $$x\mapsto\frac{P([x])}{|[x]|}$$if $[x]$ is a finite set.

Next to that it needs to be defined on $\{x\in\Omega\mid [x]\text{ not finite}\}$ as well. If $[x]$ is infinite then just let $p$ be defined on its elements on such a way that: $$\sum_{y\in[x]}p(y)=P([x])$$ Actually that works for finite sets also.